# How to change tax title in email notification using Magento?

Tags: magento, php

I would like to change the title of "TAX" for "VAT", in the email notification sending out after each orders. Please advice.

Thank you in advance

```
<!--<td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>> <?php if ($this->displayFullSummary()): ?> <div class="summary-collapse"><?php echo $this->__('Tax'); ?></div> <?php else: ?> <?php echo $this->__('Tax'); ?> <?php endif;?> </td> <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_source->getTaxAmount()) ?></td>-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `tax.phtml` from following path -

```
\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\tax\order
```

On line number 45, you will find `<?php foreach ($rates as $rate): ?>`

Remove this foreach, your tax will not be there in your emails.

Comment: Its changed according to your advice as above. However its the same, nothing changed. Cache & reindex done. How can I remove it from the email? VAT is already there so the Tax does needs to be there. See new screenshot above.

Comment: You want to remove VAT(23%) from your email only. right?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try that hope this will help

Comment: The VAT(23%) is fine, correct. However the "Tax" is not relevant so I want to remove it.

Comment: Not yet, your line above is the same as the "Tax" tag?

Comment: ok then remove last tr from same phtml file. It is containing your Tax row.

Comment: If I deleted the last tr line then the ordering could not proceed. However I comment out the following lines as below. This is hidden now. Thanks a lot for your help!! <!--<td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
        <?php if ($this->displayFullSummary()): ?>
            <div class="summary-collapse"><?php echo $this->__('Tax'); ?></div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->__('Tax'); ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </td>
    <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_source->getTaxAmount()) ?></td>-->

Comment: Try to comment tr from line number 66, please comment php code also and check again.

Comment: Yes, all sorted. Thanks a lot for your help. See above commented code.